# parallelize streamcluster with openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, pragma

I am trying to parallelize a programme called streamcluster. More specifically the function named pgain spends most time of the programme according to the Scalasca tool I used, so this is the function i should parallelize. Here you can see the function and my effort in parallelizing it. The problem is that the only thing i have achieved, is the programm to spend even more time to be executed.

The original pgain function in streamcluster:

```
double pgain ( long x, Points *points, double z, long int *numcenters )
{
int i;
int number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

static double *work_mem;
static double gl_cost_of_opening_x;
static int gl_number_of_centers_to_close;

int stride = *numcenters + 2;
//make stride a multiple of CACHE_LINE
int cl = CACHE_LINE/sizeof ( double );
if ( stride % cl != 0 ) {
    stride = cl * ( stride / cl + 1 );
}
int K = stride - 2 ; // K==*numcenters

//my own cost of opening x
double cost_of_opening_x = 0;

work_mem = ( double* ) malloc ( 2 * stride * sizeof ( double ) );
gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;
gl_number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

/*
 * For each center, we have a *lower* field that indicates
 * how much we will save by closing the center.
 */
int count = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
    if ( is_center[i] ) {
        center_table[i] = count++;
    }
}
work_mem[0] = 0;

//now we finish building the table. clear the working memory.
memset ( switch_membership, 0, points->num * sizeof ( bool ) );
memset ( work_mem, 0, stride*sizeof ( double ) );
memset ( work_mem+stride,0,stride*sizeof ( double ) );

//my *lower* fields
double* lower = &work_mem[0];
//global *lower* fields
double* gl_lower = &work_mem[stride];

for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
    float x_cost = dist ( points->p[i], points->p[x], points->dim ) * points->p[i].weight;
    float current_cost = points->p[i].cost;

    if ( x_cost < current_cost ) {

        // point i would save cost just by switching to x
        // (note that i cannot be a median,
        // or else dist(p[i], p[x]) would be 0)

        switch_membership[i] = 1;
        cost_of_opening_x += x_cost - current_cost;

    } else {

        // cost of assigning i to x is at least current assignment cost of i

        // consider the savings that i's **current** median would realize
        // if we reassigned that median and all its members to x;
        // note we've already accounted for the fact that the median
        // would save z by closing; now we have to subtract from the savings
        // the extra cost of reassigning that median and its members
        int assign = points->p[i].assign;
        lower[center_table[assign]] += current_cost - x_cost;
    }
}

// at this time, we can calculate the cost of opening a center
// at x; if it is negative, we'll go through with opening it

for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
    if ( is_center[i] ) {
        double low = z + work_mem[center_table[i]];
        gl_lower[center_table[i]] = low;
        if ( low > 0 ) {
            // i is a median, and
            // if we were to open x (which we still may not) we'd close i

            // note, we'll ignore the following quantity unless we do open x
            ++number_of_centers_to_close;
            cost_of_opening_x -= low;
        }
    }
}
//use the rest of working memory to store the following
work_mem[K] = number_of_centers_to_close;
work_mem[K+1] = cost_of_opening_x;

gl_number_of_centers_to_close = ( int ) work_mem[K];
gl_cost_of_opening_x = z + work_mem[K+1];

// Now, check whether opening x would save cost; if so, do it, and
// otherwise do nothing

if ( gl_cost_of_opening_x < 0 ) {
    //  we'd save money by opening x; we'll do it
    for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
        bool close_center = gl_lower[center_table[points->p[i].assign]] > 0 ;
        if ( switch_membership[i] || close_center ) {
            // Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
            // or i is closer to x than to its current median
            points->p[i].cost = points->p[i].weight * dist ( points->p[i], points->p[x], points->dim );
            points->p[i].assign = x;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
        if ( is_center[i] && gl_lower[center_table[i]] > 0 ) {
            is_center[i] = false;
        }
    }
    if ( x >= 0 && x < points->num ) {
        is_center[x] = true;
    }

    *numcenters = *numcenters + 1 - gl_number_of_centers_to_close;
} else {
    gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;  // the value we'll return
}

free ( work_mem );

return -gl_cost_of_opening_x;
}
```

And this is what i have done to parallelize it:

```
double pgain ( long x, Points *points, double z, long int *numcenters )
{
int i;
int number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

static double *work_mem;
static double gl_cost_of_opening_x;
static int gl_number_of_centers_to_close;

int stride = *numcenters + 2;
//make stride a multiple of CACHE_LINE
int cl = CACHE_LINE/sizeof ( double );
if ( stride % cl != 0 ) {
    stride = cl * ( stride / cl + 1 );
}
int K = stride - 2 ; // K==*numcenters

//my own cost of opening x
double cost_of_opening_x = 0;

work_mem = ( double* ) malloc ( 2 * stride * sizeof ( double ) );
gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;
gl_number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

/*
 * For each center, we have a *lower* field that indicates
 * how much we will save by closing the center.
 */
int count = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
    if ( is_center[i] ) {
        center_table[i] = count++;
    }
}
work_mem[0] = 0;

//now we finish building the table. clear the working memory.
memset ( switch_membership, 0, points->num * sizeof ( bool ) );
memset ( work_mem, 0, stride*sizeof ( double ) );
memset ( work_mem+stride,0,stride*sizeof ( double ) );

//my *lower* fields
double* lower = &work_mem[0];
//global *lower* fields
double* gl_lower = &work_mem[stride];
float x_cost=0.0;
float current_cost=0.0;

#pragma omp parallel for private(current_cost,x_cost) 
shared(cost_of_opening_x)  


for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {

    x_cost = dist ( points->p[i], points->p[x], points->dim ) * points->p[i].weight;
    current_cost = points->p[i].cost;

    if ( x_cost < current_cost ) {

        // point i would save cost just by switching to             // x
        // (note that i cannot be a median,
        // or else dist(p[i], p[x]) would be 0)

        switch_membership[i] = 1;

        cost_of_opening_x += x_cost - current_cost;
        {
        #pragma omp flush(cost_of_opening_x)
        }
    } else {

        // cost of assigning i to x is at least current assignment cost of i

        // consider the savings that i's **current** median would realize
        // if we reassigned that median and all its members to x;
        // note we've already accounted for the fact that the median
        // would save z by closing; now we have to subtract from the savings
        // the extra cost of reassigning that median and its members
        int assign = points->p[i].assign;

        lower[center_table[assign]] += current_cost - x_cost;
        {
        #pragma omp flush(lower) 
        }
    }
#pragma omp barrier
{
#pragma omp flush(lower,cost_of_opening_x)
}   
}

// at this time, we can calculate the cost of opening a center
// at x; if it is negative, we'll go through with opening it
for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
    if ( is_center[i] ) {
        double low = z + work_mem[center_table[i]];
        gl_lower[center_table[i]] = low;
        if ( low > 0 ) {
            // i is a median, and
            // if we were to open x (which we still may not) we'd close i

            // note, we'll ignore the following quantity unless we do open x
            ++number_of_centers_to_close;
            cost_of_opening_x -= low;
        }
    }
}
//use the rest of working memory to store the following
work_mem[K] = number_of_centers_to_close;
work_mem[K+1] = cost_of_opening_x;

gl_number_of_centers_to_close = ( int ) work_mem[K];
gl_cost_of_opening_x = z + work_mem[K+1];

// Now, check whether opening x would save cost; if so, do it, and
// otherwise do nothing

if ( gl_cost_of_opening_x < 0 ) {
    //  we'd save money by opening x; we'll do it
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
        bool close_center = gl_lower[center_table[points->p[i].assign]] > 0 
;
        if ( switch_membership[i] || close_center ) {
            // Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
            // or i is closer to x than to its current median
            points->p[i].cost = points->p[i].weight * dist ( points->p[i], 
points->p[x], points->dim );
            points->p[i].assign = x;
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
        if ( is_center[i] && gl_lower[center_table[i]] > 0 ) {
            is_center[i] = false;
        }
    }
    if ( x >= 0 && x < points->num ) {
        is_center[x] = true;
    }

    *numcenters = *numcenters + 1 - gl_number_of_centers_to_close;
} else {
    gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;  // the value we'll return
}

free ( work_mem );

return -gl_cost_of_opening_x;
}
```

Can you see any improvement or change that would make it faster? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not undertood the logic of your code (neither serial nor parallel). But I have tried to identify some snippets that could be parallelized. I have not compiled the code I am suggesting. So, the idea of my answer is to point out some possibilites to make your code faster. Naturally, concurrencies must be verified, shared and private variables must be analysed, etc. Based on this, my suggestion is:

```
double pgain ( long x, Points *points, double z, long int *numcenters )
{
    int i;
    int number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

    static double *work_mem;
    static double gl_cost_of_opening_x;
    static int gl_number_of_centers_to_close;

    int stride = *numcenters + 2;
    //make stride a multiple of CACHE_LINE
    int cl = CACHE_LINE/sizeof ( double );
    if ( stride % cl != 0 ) {
        stride = cl * ( stride / cl + 1 );
    }
    int K = stride - 2 ; // K==*numcenters

    //my own cost of opening x
    double cost_of_opening_x = 0;
    work_mem = ( double* ) malloc ( 2 * stride * sizeof ( double ) );
    gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;
    gl_number_of_centers_to_close = 0;

    int count = 0;
    //my *lower* fields
    double* lower;
    //global *lower* fields
    double* gl_lower;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        /*
         * For each center, we have a *lower* field that indicates
         * how much we will save by closing the center.
         */

        int i;
        #pragma omp for private(i)
        for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
            if ( is_center[i] ) {
                #pragma omp critical
                center_table[i] = count++;
            }
        }

        #pragma omp single
        work_mem[0] = 0;

        #pragma omp sections
        {
            //now we finish building the table. clear the working memory.
            #pragma omp section
            memset ( switch_membership, 0, points->num * sizeof ( bool ) );

            #pragma omp section
            memset ( work_mem, 0, stride*sizeof ( double ) );

            #pragma omp section
            memset ( work_mem+stride,0,stride*sizeof ( double ) );
        }

        #pragma omp single
        {
            lower = &work_mem[0];
            gl_lower = &work_mem[stride];
        }

        float x_cost, current_cost;

        #pragma omp for private(i, x_cost, current_cost)
        for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {

            x_cost = dist ( points->p[i], points->p[x], points->dim ) * points->p[i].weight;
            current_cost = points->p[i].cost;

            if ( x_cost < current_cost ) {

                // point i would save cost just by switching to x
                // (note that i cannot be a median,
                // or else dist(p[i], p[x]) would be 0)

                switch_membership[i] = 1;

                #pragma omp critical
                cost_of_opening_x += x_cost - current_cost;

            } else {

                // cost of assigning i to x is at least current assignment cost of i

                // consider the savings that i's **current** median would realize
                // if we reassigned that median and all its members to x;
                // note we've already accounted for the fact that the median
                // would save z by closing; now we have to subtract from the savings
                // the extra cost of reassigning that median and its members
                int assign = points->p[i].assign;

                #pragma omp critical
                lower[center_table[assign]] += current_cost - x_cost;
            }
        }

        // at this time, we can calculate the cost of opening a center
        // at x; if it is negative, we'll go through with opening it

        double low;

        #pragma omp for private(i, low)
        for ( int i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
            if ( is_center[i] ) {
                low = z + work_mem[center_table[i]];
                #pragma omp critical
                gl_lower[center_table[i]] = low;
                if ( low > 0 ) {
                    // i is a median, and
                    // if we were to open x (which we still may not) we'd close i

                    // note, we'll ignore the following quantity unless we do open x
                    #pragma omp atomic
                    ++number_of_centers_to_close;
                    #pragma omp critical
                    cost_of_opening_x -= low;
                }
            }
        }

        #pragma omp sections
        {
            //use the rest of working memory to store the following
            #pragma omp section
            work_mem[K] = number_of_centers_to_close;

            #pragma omp section
            work_mem[K+1] = cost_of_opening_x;

            #pragma omp section
            gl_number_of_centers_to_close = ( int ) work_mem[K];

            #pragma omp section
            gl_cost_of_opening_x = z + work_mem[K+1];
        }

        // Now, check whether opening x would save cost; if so, do it, and
        // otherwise do nothing
        bool close_center;

        if ( gl_cost_of_opening_x < 0 ) {
            //  we'd save money by opening x; we'll do it
            #pragma omp for private(i)
            for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
                close_center = gl_lower[center_table[points->p[i].assign]] > 0 ;
                if ( switch_membership[i] || close_center ) {
                    // Either i's median (which may be i itself) is closing,
                    // or i is closer to x than to its current median
                    points->p[i].cost = points->p[i].weight * dist ( points->p[i], points->p[x], points->dim );
                    points->p[i].assign = x;
                }
            }
            #pragma omp for private(i)
            for ( i = 0; i < points->num; i++ ) {
                if ( is_center[i] && gl_lower[center_table[i]] > 0 ) {
                    is_center[i] = false;
                }
            }
            if ( x >= 0 && x < points->num ) {
                is_center[x] = true;
            }

            #pragma omp single
            *numcenters = *numcenters + 1 - gl_number_of_centers_to_close;
        } else {
            #pragma omp single
            gl_cost_of_opening_x = 0;  // the value we'll return
        }

        #pragma omp single
        free ( work_mem );
    }

    return -gl_cost_of_opening_x;
}
```